# laravel 5.4 add index to field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration

I know this can easily be achieved by doing this:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('first_name');
$table->string('last_name');
$table->unsignedInteger('gender_id');
$table->date('date_of_birth');
$table->date('active_in_sport');
$table->unsignedInteger('people_type_id');
$table->timestamps();

$table->unique([
    'first_name',
    'last_name'
]);
$table->index('gender_id');
$table->index('people_type_id');
```

The downside of this is that Laravel first creates the table and than runs an `alter table` query.
At the moment I run into a foreign key error because of this so I'd like to add the index to the field in the create statement. How can I do this?

Comment: How would you run into a foreign key error if you're just now creating the table and foreign keys couldn't be referencing it yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't got any foreign keys there, so it's likely the issue is in another part of your code.

You can do an index inline though, instead of at the end of the migration closure. For example,`$table->unsignedInteger('gender_id')->index()`. If you like the chaining syntax you can take it a step further with `$table->integer('gender_id')->unsigned()->index()`.